# Firebase Auth, only activate account created after someone accept it

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I currently have an website that uses firebase auth as my authentication. My problem is that I don't want to open registration to everyone, only a selected few people that are supposed to use the website. I read about .htaccess and .htpasswd but since I'm hosting on firebase hosting I don't think it's possible.

My question is how can I secure the account creation? I don't want to create the accounts manually at firebase console but have the users create it on a page. Is it possible to have the account work only after someone "accept" it at the firebase console or add an extra step after creation, can I somehow protect the registration page if using firebase hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to prevent any user from **creating** an account after you enable Firebase Authentication. But the fact that they can create an account, does not necessarily mean that they can then use your application.

The typical approach for your use-case is to store a list of approved users somewhere. Since you're using Firebase Authentication, this would take the form of a list of UIDs.

So to be **authorized** to use your application a user needs to be **authenticated**, and **approved**. Firebase Authentication takes care of them being authenticated, and your back-end functionality should take care of checking their approval status.

For example, if you're using Cloud Firestore as your database, you'd store the approved user UIDs in a collection:

```
approvedUsers <collection>
  UID1 <document>
  UID2 <document>
```

And then you can check in the server-side security rules of your database that the user is authorized (authenticated and approved) before allowing them to (for example) read any data.

```
exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(document.reference))
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /myCollection/{document} {

     function isApproved() {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/approvedUsers/$(request.auth.uid))
      }

      allow read, write: if isApproved();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Right now my my collection looks like that
https://i.imgur.com/xsLQWRR.png

and my rules looks like that
```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /myCollection/{document} {

     function isApproved() {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/approvedUsers/$(request.auth.uid))
      }

      allow read, write: if isApproved();
    }
  }
}

```
But am still not able to see the data from the collection. Don't know if I should change something in the rules

Comment: I have a feeling your code may be trying to read all documents, which the rules don't allow. Keep in mind that rules don't filter data: it's your code that needs to do that. The rules then merely validate that the code does something that is allowed. If you're having a hard time making that work, consider posting a new question with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, such an MCVE would include your rules, a sample of your data, **and** the minimal **code** that are needed to reproduce the issue.